# escaping variables on RaiseFault's Payload

Tags: apigee

Hello and thanks for the support,

so I'm trying to do a custom raisefault that catches the errors from one api and reformats it. so I did this

```
<Payload contentType="application/json">
   \{
      "status": "error",
      "error": \{
        "code": "{response.status_code}",
        "description": "{response.message}",
        "subcode": "{response.subcode}"
      }
    }
 </Payload>
```

everything works great but in my message its not impossible that it may contain enters and break lines that break the json format. 
- is there a way to force some kind of sanitation over the variables? 
- or apply transformations to the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can think to do that is to run a Javascript callout first and transform the response.message variable using a regex.

Comment: can you reassign the variable from JS

Comment: already answered my question any variable defined on the js its a valid variable. thanks

Comment: To add to that, you can manipulate a lot of the flow variables in JS, but some are only available on the Client or the Target side, and some are read only. To know for sure check the variables reference at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michael's response:

You'd use

```
var responseMessage = context.getVariable("response.message");
```

to access the variable in JavaScript. After transforming it, I'd recommend saving the transformed string in a different variable:

```
context.setVariable("response_message_str", responseMessage);
```

and then accessing `response_message_str` in your `RaiseFault`.